# c# forms and mysql database code visual stidio 2010

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I just coded this:

```
Description.Text = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cell[1].Value.ToString();
ProductType.SelectedText= dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
Image.Text = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
```

at the first line, i used textbox,second line comboBox and at the last line, i used PictureBox. I put datagridview in the form. When i click the content of datagrid ,suddenly it prompt me like this `NullReferenceExeption was unhandled`, 
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object` - what is the proper code i should use?

Comment: Thanks for editing.. that what exactly what i mean..

Comment: You could add **breakpoints** and figure out which line threw the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. Then go back and see why that data is not there.

Comment: Thanks  Lars Rotgers.. I'm just a beginner when it comes to programming..  i'll try it.. have a nice day